# Merging values of a list of rules where some keys occur more than once

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, gathering

I have a list of rules resembling

```
rules = {{a -> {1, 2, 3}}, {b -> {2, 3, 4}}, {c -> {3, 4, 5}, c -> {4, 5, 6}}}
```

How can I neatly rearrange this to get a list of rules where they keys only occur once, and all their respective values are joined together? Desired output

```
{a -> {1, 2, 3}, b -> {2, 3, 4}, c -> {3, 4, 5, 6}}
```

I have what I think is an inelegant approach:

```
Flatten[
    GatherBy[rules, Keys] /.
        {r__Rule} :> Rule[First @ Keys[{r}], Union @@ Values[{r}]]
]

(* {a -> {1, 2, 3}, b -> {2, 3, 4}, c -> {3, 4, 5, 6}} *)
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Merge[{rules}, Union @@ # &]
```

> <|a -> {1, 2, 3}, b -> {2, 3, 4}, c -> {3, 4, 5, 6}|>

You can either continue to use this `Association` (this works indeed, e.g., with `ReplaceAll`) or you can convert back to a list of rules with `Normal`.

Comment: And here I was thinking `Merge` only worked with associations... Much obliged.

Comment: You're welcome.